# How to overwrite a component in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, components, angular5

I have a component `<my-component>` in Angular 5

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
templateUrl: './my.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {

click(param: string){
 console.log(param);
}
```

And in my html I have something like this:

```
<my-component (click)="click('Hello world')"></my-component>
```

I need to overwrite click function to execute:
   `console.log('Param: ' + param);`

How can I do this???

Comment: Do you have access to the source?

Comment: No, I don't. my-component for me comes as npm package

Comment: How about extending the component then? Then you'd use `<my-extended-component ...>`.

Comment: I need to overwrite the existing one with the same selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.module.ts

```
import { OriginalComponent } from './original/original.component';
import { MockOfOriginalComponent } from './mock/mock-of-original.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    OriginalComponent,
    MockOfOriginalComponent

  ],
  providers: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: 'pm-mock-of-original', component: MockOfOriginalComponent },
      { path: 'pm-original', redirectTo: 'pm-mock-of-original' },
    ]),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Your OriginalComponent

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'pm-original',
    templateUrl: 'original.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['original.component.scss']
    })

    export class OriginalComponent {

    }
```

Your MockOfOriginalComponent

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'pm-mock-of-original',
    templateUrl: 'mock-of-original.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['mock-of-original.component.scss']
    })

    export class MockOfOriginalComponent {

    }
```

The trick is the redirection in your AppModule

```
  { path: 'pm-mock-of-original', component: MockOfOriginalComponent },
  { path: 'pm-original', redirectTo: 'pm-mock-of-original' }
```

I tested this locally and it worked properly. If it doesn't try this

```
  { path: 'pm-mock-of-original', component: MockOfOriginalComponent },
  { path: 'pm-original', redirectTo: 'pm-mock-of-original', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

This also works when you import both components from (external) modules.

Comment: @Matteo Calò: If this was helpful to you I'd like you to mark this answer as solution to your problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I have a problem in console: Unexpected value '[object Object]' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Please, provide your AppModule, so that I can check where the problem might be located.

Comment: @Matteo Calò: It seems that I made a mistake. Obviously components can't be overridden this way. Only in testing-frameworks. This only works for services 'n stuff. But I have another solution. I adjusted my answer above.

Comment: It is a very interesting solution, but I inherited OriginalComponent from a dependency. So, with your solution I need to extend an inherited routingModule, how can I do that?

Comment: @Matteo Calò: This is supposed to work either. Maybe you have to add the "pathMatch: 'full'" parameter. I added it to my post above. I imported both components from their own modules into app.modules.ts and the redirection worked. Therefor it has to work too when you import the original component from an external dependency.