# How do I overwrite an existing component in angular?

Tags: angular, components, angular5, selector

I am trying to overwrite an existing component in angular.

My original component is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-orginal',
  templateUrl: './orginal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orginal.component.css']
})
export class OrginalComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

in the app.component.html I use the original component like that:

```
<app-orginal></app-orginal>
```

What you would like to do is overwrite the original component with the mock component.

This is my mock component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mock-of-orginal',
  templateUrl: './mock-of-orginal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mock-of-orginal.component.css']
})
export class MockOfOrginalComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

Related to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49327712/7717382 I tried to use this solution in my app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        OrginalComponent,
        MockOfOrginalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: 'app-mock-of-orginal', component: MockOfOrginalComponent},
            {path: 'app-orginal', redirectTo: 'app-mock-of-orginal', pathMatch: 'full'},
        ]),
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

But it does not work. What did I do wrong?

Here is my git-hub project: https://github.com/annalen/overwrite-component

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You use the words like "override" and "mock" but then you show code related to routing. Is this for a unit test?

Comment: I would like to insert a few lines of code into the app.module.ts that override the app-original component with the app-mock-of-original component.
I'm looking for something like that, but for components: {
            provide: OrginalComponent,
            useExisting: MockOfOrginalComponent
        },

Comment: I don't think this can be changed using the providers. Providers are for dependency injection. At run-time Angular will add components to the providers to be injected, but changing what the class association is doesn't change how the templates select components for creation at run-time. Keep in mind that components have a "providers" property that lets you override injectables for the component and the view. Maybe that offers some other options for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace a component with an alternative it has to replace the declaration of the original. You're example is declaring both components at the same time, but with different selectors. The key is to use the same selector, but only declare one.

```
@Component({selector: 'app-original'})
export class MockAppComponent {
      // this will replace AppComponent
}

@Component({selector: 'app-original'})
export class AppComponent {
}

// You could use a value from environment.ts
// if you need to toggle this at compile time.
const mockFlag = true;

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       mockFlag ? MockAppComponent : AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [mockFlag ? MockAppComponent : AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Angular will not allow you to declare two components that share the same selector, but you have to use that selector if you don't want to change your templates.

I'm not sure why you want to do this. Maybe this isn't want you need.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I have an angular library with two types of buttons, once a radio button and a normal button. Depending on the app, the button layout should be different.

Comment: Is it possible to control the choice of components dynamically via a SettingsService variable?

Comment: Just wondering if the `MockAppComponent` could implement/extend the `AppComponent` and then override some functions?

Comment: just to give another example why something like this could be useful. I'm trying to make my project ssr friendly, however because i have a thirdparty library being used in one of my components that is not compatible with ssr, I want to use this to replace the client side component with the "mock" one that doesn't depend on that library